# How to fill image in pdf file using pdftk

Tags: php, pdf, pdftk

This is my sample code.
I'm stuck on how to insert images into this. 
I would be grateful for any help:

```
include('autoload.php');

use mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf;

$dat = "review.png";

$pdf = new Pdf('Josco.pdf');
$pdf->fillForm(['signature'=>$dat ]);
$pdf->saveAs('my.pdf');
```

I don't know how to fill image in image type field. Please find attached 
the pdf file for reference :

```
[1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wz_mhdCFbG5o_1CgF6VlIJ4Gh70Ne8-E/view?usp=sharing
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add image in a pdf using pdftk alone. A possibility would be to use tcpdf or fpdf to generate a pdf file of a blank page with the signature located where you want. Then to use the pdftk stamp function to stamp this generated file on the source pdf

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i'm asking about form filling, i have so many form on which position of signature is not static, I  have given a name of that field and I want to fill that particular field  on each form.

Comment: Yes I understand your dilemma as I had the same, but form fields are not fillable with images with pdftk. I can tell you that form hours of research. You must pay for setasign products if you want more.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning setasign in your response! We have also been researching this for many hours. Nothing does what we want.  Found this: https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-formfiller-manual/individual-appearance/#index-3-1

Comment: @stevepowell2000 thanks for the link, yes it seems a nice way to solve this issue with the setasign product.